# Macbook setup SDL2 with vscode but linker error

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl, sdl-2

I want to setup sdl2 with vscode. However, when I run the main file, there is an error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main-9eb1c9.o
  "_SDL_DestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main-9eb1c9.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main-9eb1c9.o
  "_SDL_PollEvent", referenced from:
      _main in main-9eb1c9.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      _main in main-9eb1c9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ 建置使用中檔案",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "偵錯工具產生的工作。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // 初始化SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    // 創建視窗
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Window",
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                          800, 600,
                                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    // 主迴圈
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // 釋放資源
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to successfully create a window on Mac with vscode and sdl2 by using the makefile.
I try to use `makefile` but the error still there. Here is my makefile

```
all:
    g++ -Iinclude -Llib/SDL2 -o main src/*.cpp -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Comment: Your VSCode version fails because you did not link with the libraries, but the makefile version looks OK. Maybe you downloaded the wrong libraries, e.g. the wrong architecture?

Comment: ` "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],` does not link to any library. Remember once you have multiple cpp files or any external library with VSCode and you are not using CMakeTools or Makefile tools you must edit your tasks.json to do the linking. VSCode will not automatically link to any third party library

Comment: If you are using a Makefile have you installed the [Makefile Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) extension?